# CocoaButton loading working with constraints iOS

Tags: ios, swift, button

I installed CocoaButton in my project and wanted to use the `startLoading()` function. However it did not work as advertised, if the button had any constraints. I don't really know how to make my button the right size without them.

Has anyone managed to make it work as it is supposed to with constraints on the button?

Comment: A quick look shows "CocoaButton" manipulates the frame directly, so no, it won't work when using constraints. You *could* embed it in a view, use constraints / auto-layout on the view, and on `layoutSubviews()` set the button frame to fill the view. Or something along those lines.